# Power expansion of $f(x)= x^2 \arctan{{x-1 \over x+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I am looking for the power expansion of $f(x)= x^2 \arctan{{x-1 \over x+1}}$. I am aware that $\arctan{x}=x-{x^3 \over 3}+{x^5 \over 5}-{x^7 \over 7}+ \dots$, so it seems that
$$f(x)={x-1 \over x+1}x^2-{1 \over 3}\left({x-1 \over x+1}\right)^3x^2+{1 \over 5}\left({x-1 \over x+1}\right)^5x^2-{1 \over 7}\left({x-1 \over x+1}\right)^7x^2+\dots$$
This is obviously very clunky. Is there a relatively simple way to rearrange this sum to fit the from $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$?

Comment: $\arctan{x}=x-{x^3 \over 3}+{x^5 \over 5}-{x^7 \over 7}+ \dots $ ... not factorials ! ... How many terms in the expansion do you need ?

Comment: Use the definition of a power series and find a pattern. Don't worry about proving it, it might give some insight into a proof.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Ideally, an expression of the form $\sum a_n x^n$.

Comment: The factor of $x^2$ is a red herring (you can put it in later) ... calculate $\frac{d}{dx} \tan^{-1}(\frac{x-1}{x+1})$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the trigonometric identity (see e.g. Abramowitz/Stegun 4.4.36 or 
http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.24.E17)
$$\arctan\frac{z_1 z_2-1}{z_1+z_2}=\arctan(z_1)- \mathrm{arccot}(z_2)$$
substitute $z_1=x, z_2=1$ and get
$$\arctan\frac{x-1}{x+1}=\arctan(x)- \mathrm{arccot}(1)=\arctan(x)- \frac{\pi}{4}$$
I guess you can continue.